# django: register listeners in models.py and cyclic import problems

Tags: python, django, django-signals, cyclic-reference

I'm working on some signal listeners, which creates records from a model. And in django docs it is said listeners should be registered in models.py. Because the listeners are quite big in lines, I would like to separate their logics from the file of models.py. Seems like it's already causing cyclic importing problems in my case. What's the best way of avoiding this problem while keeping the codes separated?

currently it's like this:
models.py

```
class foo(models.Model):
    #model definition

import listeners
```

listeners.py

```
import models
def fun(sender,**kwargs):
    bar=models.foo()
    #listener logics....

from AnotherApp.models import AnotherModel
post_save.connect(fun,sender=AnotherModel)
```

Comment: Why do you think you're having cyclic import problems?

Comment: I'm calling 'super(foo,self).save(*args,**kwargs)' and it fires an error of something like "super has argument 1 as NoneType", after some searching I think it's a cyclic import problem

Comment: It's a cyclic import because you're importing listeners in models.py and models in listeners.py.
It's pretty sad that a rude comment gets four upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a funny hack:

```
from django.db.models import get_model

import models

def fun(sender,**kwargs):
    # still better than doing the import in the function isn't it ...
    if sender != get_model('anotherapp', 'anothermodel'):
        return

    bar=models.foo()
    #listener logics....

post_save.connect(fun)
```

And this might even work but i can't say:

```
post_save.connect(fun, sender=get_model('anotherapp', 'anothermodel'))
```

BTW, there are better names than *listeners*: [**reciever** is the Django-ish name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions), and [**slot** is the common name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots).

Anyhow, I can't be more helpful because **I cannot reproduce your issue with the code you pasted**. Please, make sure that you pasted code that is able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks jpic for the awesome hacks and tips! :) Sorry for my pool question description, I'll try to add in more details, it's super complicated. Working on it for a whole day don't give much results, currently I put the signal connect in __init__.py for a work round.

Comment: You should copy your code, remove everything that isn't necessary to reproduce the problem, and paste what's left.